# Why do I have to wait until I can accept a answer I posted myself

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

When I answer my own question, I have to wait two days until I can accept the answer.

Why is this set to such a long time span? If I solved the problem myself, I want to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for the community to offer a better answer.

Comment: but if you already solved it on your own, then you don't need a better answer since the problem is no more. The answers that come after that are too late anyway.

Comment: @Alvar did you give a read to this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer

Comment: I don't have to agree with you.

Comment: @Alvar I'm not saying my "opinion" anyways, but just relaying what the creators said.